# how can i get RouteValueDictionary values from Page.RouteData.DataTokens

Tags: c#, asp.net

how can i get RouteValueDictionary values  from Page.RouteData.DataTokens

My Code:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("NewsDetails", "NewsDetails/{id}/{title}",
                    "~/NewsDetails.aspx", false,
                     new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", 0 },
                     { "title", string.Empty } });
```

i want get id and title  because Page.RouteData.Values does not working

[image]

thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to get them from Page.RouteData.DataTokens? Try to get them from Page.RouteData.Values

Comment: Page.RouteData.Values  does not  show values (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Comment: Strange, just tried it and works as expected. Maybe you have some other custom stuff which breaks it?

Comment: Have you tried Page.RouteData.DataTokens["title"]? 
I was able to put values in DataTokens collection but i used another MapPageRoute overload
            routes.MapPageRoute("NewsDetails", "NewsDetails/{id}/{title}",
                    "~/Test1.aspx", false,
                     new RouteValueDictionary { { "id", 0 },
                     { "title", string.Empty }}, new RouteValueDictionary(), new RouteValueDictionary { {"test", 12}});

Comment: Strange Page.RouteData.Values is worked now!!!! in another pc    thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Page.RouteData.Values` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too; `Page.RouteData.Values` was not returning any values but I could see the passed value under `DataTokens`.

It turns out that `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls` was messing with my route mapping, So after I read [this article by Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) -->  and used `Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()` to get the values.

It worked but I didn't want to have to iterate through all the values to assign them (as suggested in the article). So, instead of using `Request.GetFriendlyUrlSegments()`, I changed the order of my route mappings (under `RouteConfig.cs`) so that `routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);` is registered after all the other routes have been registered.

It was only after I changed the ordering of the routes that I got my values from `Page.RouteData.Values`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following to access specific keys:

```
((System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult)response).RouteValues["KeyName"]
```